# Bootstrap 4.6 navbar items with dropdowns don't vertically align with other menu items

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a fairly simple navbar but can't figure out why the nav items with a dropdown don't vertically align with the other items.  Devtools shows that the 'li's are the same height - 54, but that the 'a's are 32 on the regular items and 34 on those with drop downs.

[image]

```
<div class='d-flex align-items-center px-5'>
  <div class='nav d-none d-xl-block' id='nav-menu-xl'>
  <nav class='nav-menu'>
    <ul>
      <li class='nav-item'>
        <a class='nav-link' href=''>Members</a>
      </li>
      <li class='nav-item drop-down'>
        <a class='nav-link' href=''>Benefits</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=''>Benefit 1</a></li>
```

I've watched devtools and compared comuted until my eyes were watering and don't see why one would be 2 pixels different than the other.

Comment: Given you're using Bootstrap, why is your dropdown class `drop-down` and not the Bootstrap's `dropdown`? Is that a custom class you are using? Also your dropdown html looks different that what Bootstrap offers. Could you make a JSFiddle so we can debug?

Comment: Thanks - I fixed that to dropdown and found the issue was a Fontawesome replacement of the default BS caret down.

Comment: I'm glad you found the problem. Post it as an answer, and accept it as the solution!